# Is there a way to transfer objects to a .json file without using serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm been searching the web for a way to transfer an object to a `.json` file without using `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Are there any simpler ways of doing this? I'm new to programming and wanting to learn how exactly this transfer process works on foundational level?

Comment: Using json.net you can build a JObject and write its string representation in a text file

Comment: Well you could reinvent the wheel if you chose, but, its a lot of work you could avoid

Comment: There are alternative serializers, but the process of "converting objects to some text/binary representation so you can transfer the data elsewhere" *is* serialization.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm wondering if by "without using serialization" the asker really means "without using System.Web.Script.Serialization" as in the question body. Ah, the joys of capitalization and semantics.

Comment: @BoltClock it is, he only said he does not want to use System.Web.Script.Serialization

Comment: @BoltClock: I suspect that's the case, but I want them to be aware of the difference between "a specific serializer" and "the concept of serialization"

Comment: @nkoniishvt: That's what is in the body of the question, but the title of the question is just "serialization". Given the OP's newness, I think it's worth clarifying things for them.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what I'm meaning either. My professor wants me to learn about .json file so when I come to using a SQL database I'll know exactly what's going on behind the scenes of my code. He told me serialization is the cheating way of doing it if you don't know exactly what's going on behind the sences. He said learn the foundations firsts so you don't 'shoot yourself in the foot' using code you don't fully understand. Hope this clarifies, thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Because of its efficiency, most C# developers use `Json.NET` as the go-to library for all things JSON related.

In your case, you can avoid using the built-in `System.Web.Script.Serialization` and use JSON.NET instead, which has not only simpler syntax, but also better performance and is regularly updated on NuGet.

To install the `Json.NET` package, you can use NuGet via PowerShell:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

or via user interface in Visual Studio - in Solution Explorer, right-click the References node and choose Manage NuGet Packages. Then search for `Newtonsoft.Json` and Install.

Now you can use the library as follows:

```
//add this to the using statements in your .cs file
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//use this to serialize any variable to JSON string
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( variable );

//use this to deserialize it back from JSON string, where TheTypeOf your
//variable is, well, the type of your variable :-)
var deserializedVariable = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheTypeOfYourVarialbe>( jsonString );
```